# OpenCV col-wise standard deviation result vs MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv3.0

I've seen linked questions but I can't understand why MATLAB and OpenCV give different results.

1. MATLAB Code

   ```matlab
   >> A = [6 4 23 -3; 9 -10 4 11; 2 8 -5 1]
   A =
    6     4    23    -3
    9   -10     4    11
    2     8    -5     1

   >> Col_step_1 = std(A, 0, 1)
   Col_step_1 =
    3.5119    9.4516   14.2945    7.2111

   >> Col_final = std(Col_step_1)
   Col_final =
    4.5081
   ```
2. Using OpenCV and this function:

   ```cpp
   double getColWiseStd(cv::Mat in)
   {
       CV_Assert( in.type() == CV_64F );

       cv::Mat meanValue, stdValue, m2, std2;
       cv::Mat colSTD(1, A.cols, CV_64F);
       cv::Mat colMEAN(1, A.cols, CV_64F);       

       for (int i = 0; i < A.cols; i++)
       {           
           cv::meanStdDev(A.col(i), meanValue, stdValue);
           colSTD.at<double>(i) = stdValue.at<double>(0);
           colMEAN.at<double>(i) = meanValue.at<double>(0);
       }

       std::cout<<"\nCOLstd:\n"<<colSTD<<std::endl;
       cv::meanStdDev(colSTD, m2, std2);
       std::cout<<"\nCOLstd_f:\n"<<std2<<std::endl;


       return std2.at<double>(0,0);
   }
   ```

   Applied to the same matrix yields the following:

   ```cpp
   Matrix: 
   [6,   4, 23, -3;
    9, -10,  4, 11;
    2,   8, -5,  1]

   COLstd:
   [2.867441755680876, 7.71722460186015, 11.67142760000773, 5.887840577551898]

   COLstd_f:
   [3.187726614989861]
   ```

I'm pretty sure that the OpenCV and MATLAB `std` function are correct, and thus can't find what I'm doing wrong, am I missing a type conversion? Something else?

Comment: In MATLAB, if you evaluate `Col_step_1 = std(A, 1, 1);`  `Col_final=std(Col_step_1,1);`, do you get the same result as that of OpenCV?

Comment: Indeed, well it does work now. I thought 0 was the normalization I needed on matlab, its not, parameter needs to be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard deviation you're calculating in OpenCV is normalised by number of observations (`N`) whereas you're calculating standard deviation in MATLAB  normalised by `N-1` (which is also the default normalisation factor in MATLAB and is known as *[Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction)*). Hence there is the difference.

You can normalise by `N` in MATLAB by selecting the second input argument as `1`:

```matlab
Col_step_1 = std(A, 1, 1); 
Col_final = std(Col_step_1, 1);
```